# Need help for code analysis Lucene.Net search results asp.net

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I was looking for good code for searching index using lucene.net. i got one look promising but i got some confusion. if possible anyone who is familiar with lucene.net then please have look at the code and tell me why the person construct that code in that way.

from where i got the code...url as follows
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms

### here is code

```
private static IEnumerable<SampleData> _search
(string searchQuery, string searchField = "") {
// validation
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", ""))) return new List<SampleData>();

// set up lucene searcher
using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false)) {
    var hits_limit = 1000;
    var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

    // search by single field
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField)) {
        var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, searchField, analyzer);
        var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);
        var hits = searcher.Search(query, hits_limit).ScoreDocs;
        var results = _mapLuceneSearchResultsToDataList(hits, searcher);
        analyzer.Close();
        searcher.Close();
        searcher.Dispose();
        return results;
    }
    // search by multiple fields (ordered by RELEVANCE)
    else {
        var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser
            (Version.LUCENE_29, new[] { "Id", "Name", "Description" }, analyzer);
        var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);
        var hits = searcher.Search
        (query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
        var results = _mapLuceneSearchResultsToDataList(hits, searcher);
        analyzer.Close();
        searcher.Close(); 
        searcher.Dispose();
        return results;
    }
}
}
```

### i have couple of question here for the above routine

```
1) why the developer of this code replace all * & ? to empty string in search term
2) why search once with QueryParser and again by MultiFieldQueryParser
3) how developer detect that search term has one word or many words separated by space.
4) how wild card search can be done using this code....where to change in code for handling wild card.

5) how to handle search for similar word like if anyone search with helo then hello related result should come.

var hits = searcher.Search(query, 1000).ScoreDocs;

6) when my search result will return 5000 record and then if i limit like 1000 then how could i      show next 4000 in pagination fashion.what is the object for giving the limit...i think for    fastness but if i specify limit the how can i show other results....what would be the logic
```

i will be glad if someone discuss about all my points. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) why the developer of this code replace all * & ? to empty string in
>   search term

Because those are special characters for wildcard search. What the author does - he checks if a search query has something else along with wildcards. You don't usually want to search for "*", for example.

> 2) why search once with QueryParser and again by
>   MultiFieldQueryParser

He doesn't search with QueryParsers per se, but he's parsing a search query (string) and making a bunch of objects out of it. Those objects are then consumed by a `Searcher` object, which performs actual search.

> 3) how developer detect that search term has one
>   word or many words separated by space.

That's something a Parser object should care about, not the developer.

> 4) how wild card search can be
>   done using this code....where to change in code for handling wild
>   card.

The wildcards are specified in a `searchQuery` parameter. Specifying "test*" will count as a wildcard, for example. Details are [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html).

> 5) how to handle search for similar word like if anyone search with
>   helo then hello related result should come.

I think you want a [fuzzy](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) search.

> 6) when my search result will return 5000 record and then if i limit
>   like 1000 then how could i      show next 4000 in pagination
>   fashion.what is the object for giving the limit...i think for
>   fastness but if i specify limit the how can i show other
>   results....what would be the logic

Here's an [article](http://hrycan.com/2010/02/10/paginating-lucene-search-results/) about that.

UPD: About multiple fields. Logic is following:

- If `searchField` is specified, than use simple parser, that will produce query like `searchField: value1 seachField: value2... etc`.
- If, however that parameter isn't there, then it assumes, that passed `searchQuery` will specify fields and values like `"field1: value1 field2: value2"`. Example is on the same syntax [page](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields), as I previously mentioned.

UPD2: Don't hesitate to look for Java documentation and examples for Lucene, as this is initially a Java project (hence, there's a lot of Java examples and tutorials). Lucene.NET is a ported project and both projects share a lot of functionality and classes.

UPD3: About fuzzy search, you might also want to implement your own [analyzer for synonyms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32201/Lucene-Net-Custom-Synonym-Analyzer) search (we used that technique in one of commercial projects, which I worked on, to handle common typos along with synonyms).

Comment: all your explanation was good but answer 2 & 3 was not sufficient. it is very clear in code that when search will begin with single field & when with multiple field. there is two section in code one search on single field & one search on multiple field. but the funny things was there was no code to detect whether search will perform on single field or on multiple field. if possible please discuss in more detail those points. thanks

Comment: thanks for ur time & answer. what is the meaning of this line if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField)) {
if searchField is not empty or null then search begin on single field otherwise if null or empty then search will do multifield search. may i could be wrong to understand that area. if possible put some light over there.

Comment: @Thomas, you're absolutely right about this line. If `searchField` is set, then it will perform standard query parsing (it still can be multi-field, depending on a `searchQuery`), where a `searchField` will be a default field for search.